# MySQL doesn't return any row from second query onwards

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I've got an object which interacts with MySQL where the first time that I use, works fine and give me all the data from a query, but when I try to re-use I've got zero rows when the query is well done and returns data in mysql. I'm using MySQL 8.0

This is the code:

```
tcm = FIBAColourMap()
for p in players:
    args = [p["id"], id_competition]
    print("id player: {}".format(p["id"]))
    search = SearchDataFIBA(args, "player.shots.by.competition=")
    if search.get_result().getTotalRows() > 0:
        shots = search.get_result().getData()
        for s in shots:
            x = float(FIBASCReport.adjust_x(s["x"]))
            y = float(FIBASCReport.adjust_y(s["y"]))
            print("x: {} - y: {}".format(x, y))
            color = tcm.image.getpixel((x,y))
            color = ("#%02x%02x%02x" % color).upper()
            if tcm.exists_color(color):
                if int(s["m"]) == 0:
                    tcm.set_scored_shots(color, 1)
                else:
                    tcm.set_failed_shots(color, 1)
            else:
                if int(s["m"]) == 0:
                    tcm.set_scored_shots("OTROS", 1)
                else:
                    tcm.set_failed_shots("OTROS", 1)
    else:
        print("Jugadora con id: {} NO ha realizado ningún tiro en competicion: {}".format(p["id"], id_competition))
return tcm
```

Here, I've got a search object called SearchDataFIBA which works fine the first time. But when it executes a second time, because are inside a for loop, this object doesn't return anything and I don't know why :(

This object, internally calls this method to execute the query:

```
def query(self, sql, data):
    """Returns a ResultData object"""
    # try:
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
        totalRows = cursor.execute(sql, data)
        print("Total Rows: " + str(totalRows))
        print("Ultima query: " + cursor.mogrify(sql, data))
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        if totalRows > 0:
            result = ResultData(RESULT.RESULT_OK, data, totalRows)
        else:
            result = ResultData(RESULT.RESULT_OK, None, totalRows)
        return result
```

The first excution of this code print the query executed and the total rows returned. Always return a query well defined which works in mysql but from second time execution this querys doesn't return any row when it have to returns rows.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit I:**

*ResultData object*

```
class ResultData(object):
    """Objeto que contendrá el resultado de una consulta"""
    def __init__(self, result, data, totalRows):
        self.setResult(result)
        self.setTotalRows(totalRows)
        self.setData(data)


    """Setters & Getters"""
    def setResult(self, result):
        self.result = result

    def getResult(self):
        return self.result

    def setTotalRows(self, tr):
        if tr != None:
            self.totalRows = int(tr)
        else:
            self.totalRows = None

    def getTotalRows(self):
        return self.totalRows

    def setData(self, data):
        """Diccionario que contiene los datos devueltos desde la BBDD"""
        if self.getTotalRows() != None and data != None:
            self.data = data.copy()
        else:
            self.data = None

    def getData(self):
        return self.data
```

**Edit II:**

I have found something weird. First time I'm inside the for loop I call SearchDataFIBA object and I open the connection and make the query. This query returns correctly the data, so return to the beginnig of the for loop, but I don't close the connection (don't write a message writed for the destructor function). I make another query well defined with correct values, like this, for example:

select sc.* from tbl030_shots_chart sc, tbl006_player_team pt, tbl007_game g, tbl004_jornada j, tbl012_competition c where pt.id = 67 and pt.id_player_feb = sc.id_fiba and sc.id_game = g.id and g.id_jornada = j.id and j.id_competition = c.id and c.id = 3

Here is the return of this query in mysql:

[image]

But this query in my code doesn't return anything and at the end of the for loop, before to return, it's called the destructor and closed my connection:

[image]

Then, I start from the beginning of the for loop again and go on.

**Edit III:**

I create the connection with this code:

```
    self.connection = pymysql.connect(host = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_HOST,
                                  user = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_USER,
                                  password = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_PSWD,
                                  db = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_NAME,
                                  charset = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_CHARSET,
                                  cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

And the problem is produced in the line *totalRows = cursor.execute(sql, data)* of this code:

```
def query(self, sql, data):
    """Método que devuelve un objeto ResultData con el resultado de la consulta"""
    # try:
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
        print("sql: {} - data: {}".format(sql, data))
        totalRows = cursor.execute(sql, data)
        print("Total Rows: " + str(totalRows))
        print("Ultima query: " + cursor.mogrify(sql, data))
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        if totalRows > 0:
            result = ResultData(RESULT.RESULT_OK, data, totalRows)
        else:
            result = ResultData(RESULT.RESULT_OK, None, totalRows)
        return result
```

When I call this function, always the values of variables sql and data are correct. But when is executed *totalRows = cursor.execute(sql, data)* the first time returns data but second time and nexts doesn't return anything when sql and data variables are correct. The connection is closed at the end of the for loop.

**Edit IV:**

I have updated my code, simplify and put together to test it. This code executes the same query but with different parameters n-times. The first time, the execution of the query returns data, th second time and nexts doesn't return any data when if execute the query in mysql returns data.

This is the code:

```
def get_team_colour_map(self, players, id_competition):
    tcm = FIBAColourMap()
    for p in players:
        args = [p["id"], id_competition]
        print("id player: {}".format(p["id"]))
        conn = pymysql.Connect(host = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_HOST,
                                      user = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_USER,
                                      password = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_PSWD,
                                      db = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_NAME,
                                      charset = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_CHARSET,
                                      cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            print("args: {}".format(args))
            cursor.execute("select sc.* from tbl030_shots_chart sc, tbl006_player_team pt, tbl007_game g, tbl004_jornada j, tbl012_competition c where pt.id = %s and pt.id_player_feb = sc.id_fiba and sc.id_game = g.id and g.id_jornada = j.id and j.id_competition = c.id and c.id = %s", args)
            data = cursor.fetchall()
            print("Total rows: {}".format(cursor.rowcount))
            if cursor.rowcount > 0:
                for s in data:
                    x = float(FIBASCReport.adjust_x(s["x"]))
                    y = float(FIBASCReport.adjust_y(s["y"]))
                    color = tcm.image.getpixel((x,y))
                    color = ("#%02x%02x%02x" % color).upper()
                    if tcm.exists_color(color):
                        if int(s["m"]) == 0:
                            tcm.set_scored_shots(color, 1)
                        else:
                            tcm.set_failed_shots(color, 1)
                    else:
                        if int(s["m"]) == 0:
                            tcm.set_scored_shots("OTROS", 1)
                        else:
                            tcm.set_failed_shots("OTROS", 1)
            else:
                #tcm = None
                print("Jugadora con id: {} NO ha realizado ningún tiro en competición: {}".format(p["id"], id_competition))
    return tcm
```

Inside the for loop we print the id player and the arguments that I pass to the query with the instrucctions

```
print("id player: {}".format(p["id"]))
print("args: {}".format(args))
```

This code, the first time returns me:

[image]

And the query returns me data. You can check it because Total Rows returns a number > 0.

The second time the for loop is executed. The values are:

[image]

How you can see, the code returns 0 rows, but If I execute the query in mysql, I've got data:

[image]

So, what are happen to don't get data the second time that I make a query. Why I don't get rows from my query? Why cursor.fetchall() returns empty data?

Here you can see how returns empty data and the query is correctly defined.

[image]

I don't understand anything :(

Comment: This type of problem often happens when you try to reuse a generator that you think is a list. It's hard to tell where that might be happening here, there's so much code missing. Like what is `ResultData()`?

Comment: Hi @Barmar. Thank you for your answer!!! I've updated my original post with the code of ResultData object.

Comment: What does `print(shots)` show?

Comment: The first time, when the query works returns me: shots: [{'id': 417, 'id_game': 4, 'line': 64, 'id_fiba': 155997, 'name': 'M. Xargay', 'quarter': 'Q1', 'm': 0, 'x': Decimal('384.00'), 'y': Decimal('36.00'), 'team': 1, 'date_insert': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22, 11, 56, 31)}, {'id': 419, 'id_game': 4, 'line': 66, 'id_fiba': 155997, 'name': 'M. Xargay', 'quarter': 'Q1', 'm': 1, 'x': Decimal('350.50'), 'y': Decimal('132.50'), 'team': 1, 'date_insert': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22, 11, 56, 31)}]
The other times, I have got nothing because the query returns zero rows

Comment: Is `self.connection.cursor()` returning a new cursor, or caching the cursor object and returning that?

Comment: self.connection is created on the constructor of the object SearchDataFIBA. This object, SearchDataFIBA is created each time inside of for loop

Comment: Something is being reused instead of starting fresh, but I can't see it in any of the code you've shown or described.

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the correct parameters to `query()` each time?

Comment: Yes, always passing the correct params to the query. For example, this query is well defined after passed params to it: select sc.* from tbl030_shots_chart sc, tbl006_player_team pt, tbl007_game g, tbl004_jornada j, tbl012_competition c where pt.id = 67 and pt.id_player_feb = sc.id_fiba and sc.id_game = g.id and g.id_jornada = j.id and j.id_competition = c.id and c.id = 3
This query returns rows in mysql but returns nothing with my code :(

Comment: Is possible that the destructor is not called at the end of the for loop and don't close the connection?

Comment: `with` is supposed to do that. But even if it didn't, that shouldn't affect a different connection and cursor.

Comment: I have checked if I close the connection before to open another one and I close the connection before to close it :( I don't know what happen :(

Comment: @Barmar, I have added more information to my original post

Comment: You've really complicated things by creating your own DAL, and it's really hard for us to debug a module that we can't see and try ourselves.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your appreciated help @Barmar. I'm going to put all the code in a function to simplify the search of the mistake.

Comment: Hi @Barmar!!! Sorry If I'm disturbing you with my problem. But I have updated my original post and simplified and I'm still getting the same error. :(

Comment: Step Debuggers exist for a reason!